# Find the points of the line $r$ such that the distance is 3

Tags: linear-algebra

I was writing this question when I realized my error, so to not spend what I've typed, here's the question answered for somebody who might find it useful.

I have this line:

$$x +y = 2 \\x = y+z$$

And I have to find its points that are at a distance $3$ of the point $A = (0,2,1)$. This is what i've done:

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I found the parametric equation of the line, that is:

$$\begin{align}x &= 1 + \frac{1}{2}\lambda \\y &= 1-\frac{1}{2}\lambda\\z &= 0 + \lambda\end{align}$$
*by supposing $z = \lambda$ and solving the simple system of $x$ and $y$.

Then, a point of the line $r$ has this type:

$$(1+\frac{1}{2}\lambda,1-\frac{1}{2}\lambda, \lambda)$$

So what I did is to suppose this point has the distance $3$ from $A$, by using the distance formula:

$$\sqrt{[0 - (1+\frac{1}{2}\lambda)]^2 + [2 - (1-\frac{1}{2}\lambda)]^2, [1 - \lambda]^2} = 3$$

[Solving](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%5B0-%5B1%2b1/2%20l%5D%5D%5E2%20%2b%20%5B2%20-%20%5B1-1/2%20l%5D%5D%5E2%20%2b%20%5B1-l%5D%5E2%29%5E1/2%20=%203) this we have: 
$\lambda = 2$ or $\lambda = -2$
So plugging these values in the generic point we assumed:

$$(1+\frac{1}{2}\color{Blue}{2},1-\frac{1}{2}\color{Blue}{2}, \color{Blue}{2}) = (2,0,2)$$

$$(1+\frac{1}{2}\color{Blue}{(-2)},1-\frac{1}{2}\color{Blue}{(-2)}, \color{Blue}{(-2)}) = (0,2,-2)$$